# How do you connect a set of (UILabels, UIButtons) etc. to an IBOutletCollection in one shot?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Storyboard I selected a dozen UILabels and ctrl-dragged to the ready and waiting IBOutletCollection statement:

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *myLabels;
```

This appeared to work - i.e. the @property statement magically highlighted and the connections were seemingly made.  All 12 items remained selected within storyboard. This turned out to be a head fake: via attributes inspector I saw that only ONE of the 12 connections was actually made, and I had to repeat the ctrl-drag operation 11 more times from each other label to complete all the connections.

Is there supposed to be a way to make all the connections for an outlet collection at once? Seems like there should be (or there should at least be some negative feedback if you can't).